# AngularJS - get relative coordinates to the container object, within SVG on mouse click WITH HOVER STYLE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angularjs

I want to get the relative mouse coordinates to the blue div on mouse click, but ALSO apply the hover style.
The problem is: If I use the "pointer-events=visible" property setting, the relative coordinates to the polygon-bounding-box will be returned, not relative to the container div. If I use "pointer-events:none", the coordinates are correct but hover style is missing. I'm using AngularJS but I want to avoid JQuery.

Here is my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/aun47wxo/

```js
**JS**
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

mydiv.onclick = function(event) {
 var  rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
alert((event.clientX-rect.left).toString().concat("; ",(event.clientY-rect.top).toString()));
 
 }
```

```css
**CSS**

polygon {
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: red;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events:visible;   
                    /*setting to "none" will return the right
                    coordinates but the hover style will missing
                     */
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
**HTML**

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br>
<div id="myDiv" style="background-color:blue">
<object id="svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 999 799">
    <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,10" />    
    <polygon points="445,161 345,174 500,270"/>
  </svg>
</object>
</div
```